# If statment on Data without using $request variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i'm trying check if the user is an Admin so i can restrict that URL from other users, so far i tried this code :

```
 public function Adminp(){
    $data = ['LoggedUserInfo' =>Utilisateurs::where('id','=',session('LoggedUser'))->first() ];
    $utilisateurs = Utilisateurs::all();
    $utilisateur->role = $_GET['role'];
    if($utilisateur->role == 'Admin'){
        return view('Admin.admin-dashboard', $data, compact('utilisateurs'));
    }
    else{
        return abort(404);
     }
}
```

all i get are errors

Comment: what errors? besides the obvious ones

Comment: Undefined array key "role"

Comment: okay, you have to make sure it is defined before trying to use it ... next ... and you have random parenthesis in your code for some reason

Comment: how do i define it tho ? , i mean , why doesn't this methode work for me ?

Comment: why would it be defined? do you know what the super globals are? do you know what `$_GET` is? and you are using Laravel, why would you not use the `Request` object?

Comment: i wanna see if the user is an Admin or not , and role is a variable in my Database , i'm trying to do that without using $request , if defining would fix the problem , idm trying that

Comment: do you know what `$_GET` is? it has nothing to do with your database ... im trying to figure out where you are getting this stuff from as its all unrelated things you are throwing together

Comment: yes i know that , i already tried to do it with a $request , but didn't work as well

Comment: tried to do what with `$request`? can you provide context to what you are saying .... what data do you think you so badly need to get from the incoming request?   and why are you not using the authentication system

Comment: ye , i've been trying to fix that problem for 3 hours now , i'm kinda trying anything i find on my way hoping for it to work

Comment: fix what problem? context

Comment: okey , so i have 3 types of users , Admin - supervisor - Agent , i already can gave them separate routes on login depending on the role , but if one of them connect as an Agent and alters the URL to "list-user" as an example , it'll take him there without restriction , knowning that that route is only defined for Admin users only , i'm trying to prevent that from happening without altering much in my code , that's why i'm trying to retreive the role and do an if statment on it to redirect me to 404 page if not Admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just guessing at what you are doing. I will assume you just want to see if the User that you retrieved from the database has the role you are looking for ... you should be using the authentication system for this and a Middleware to do the filtering, but

```
public function Adminp()
{
    $user = Utilisateurs::findOrFail(session('LoggedUser'));

    if ($user->role == 'Admin') {
        return view('Admin.admin-dashboard', [
            'LoggedUserInfo' => $user,
            'utilisateurs' => Utilisateurs::all(),
        ]);
    }

    return abort(404);
}
```

Let me stress this again though, you should be using the Authentication system and a Middleware to do the filtering instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: that was kind of the assignement , to make an authentification system of my own , i could've worked with Jetstream and it would've been way easier , thank you again

Comment: @AmineGhandi a middleware would still be an improvement as you could assign the middleware to any routes you want to do this check instead of doing it in your action for each one

Comment: @lagbox I don't want to be picky at all, but I would invert the `if` so it is better for future new devs (so they don't get used to `if` everything and have a beautiful `if` cascade)

Comment: @matiaslauriti agreed, just keeping their structure so they understand what was done

Answer (score 0):

```
$utilisateurs = Utilisateurs::all();
```

This will return you array of `Utilisateurs` and in the next line you are trying to get role property that will never exist in that array you need to get only one user not the array of all users.

Comment: the next line is trying to access `$utilisateur` not `$utilisateurs`

Comment: $utilisateur and that is undefined i hope you got my point

Comment: yup, its not good either way `;-)`

Comment: that's not the problem :/